# Rotate and scale a point around different origins

Tags: matrices, rotations, geometric-transformation

I am trying to rotate an arbitrary, 2D point (x,y) around another point (a,b), and at the same time, scale it from a different point (c,d). To transform the point, I must use a 3x3 transformation matrix.

For example, say I have a rectangle. I want to rotate its topleft point around its center, and scale it around its topleft:

Given point: \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y \end{pmatrix} rotational origin: \begin{pmatrix} a\\ b \end{pmatrix} and scaling origin: \begin{pmatrix} c\\ d \end{pmatrix}

(1) rotate (x,y) around (a,b)

(2) scale (x,y) from (c,d)

I know I can transform it around one origin using homogeneous coordinates, but how I can incorporate different origins for scaling and rotating in just one transformation matrix?

Comment: "At the same time" is the wrong phrase. You have to rotate first then scale, or scale then rotate. When $(a,b)=(c,d)$ you get the same result in either order, but the order is important in general.

Comment: To take your example, do you rotate around the center and then scale against the rotated top-left?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews well if I rotate it first, then I will have to scale it along its axis as to not deform the rectangle. And if I scale it first, then I will have to rotate it around the scaled center

Comment: What is "its axis" that you are scaling around?

Comment: Since it rotates, its "axis" is also rotated at some angle, so wouldn't that mess up the scaling if I were to scale from a different point than I did with rotation?

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Are you performing the dilation relative to the _original_ top left or the top left after rotation? Either way, construct the individual transformation matrices and multiply them together, or just apply each one in turn.

Comment: @amd the topleft of the rectangle even after rotation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you state in your question, you require the transformation matrix. You will need the concept of [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) to perform the translation components in matrix form. You also need to know how to construct a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) and [scaling matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_(geometry)) in two dimensions.

Rotation and scaling matrices are usually defined around the origin. To perform these transformations about an arbitrary point, you would translate the point about which the transformation is to occur to the origin, perform the transformation as normal, and then undo the translation. This process is then repeated for each transformation required.

The counter-clockwise rotation of a point $p=(x,y)$ to its image $p^\prime$ by an angle of $\theta$ around the point $(a,b)$ is
$$
p^\prime=Rp=\overbrace{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&a\\0&1&b\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{Translate back}}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{Normal rotation matrix}}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-a\\0&1&-b\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{Translate}}}^{\text{Complete rotation matrix $R$}}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}}_{p}.
$$

Similarly, to scale a point $p=(x,y)$ to its image $p^\prime$ in the $x$ direction by $s_x$ and $y$ direction by $s_y$ from the point $(a,b)$ is
$$
p^\prime=Sp=\overbrace{\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&a\\0&1&b\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{Translate back}}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}s_x&0&0\\0&s_y&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{Normal scalingmatrix}}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-a\\0&1&-b\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}}_{\text{Translate}}}^{\text{Complete scaling matrix $S$}}
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\1\end{bmatrix}}_{p}.
$$

The combined transformation matrix I will denote $T$ to perform the complete transformation will be either $T=SR$, if the rotation is performed first, followed by the scaling, or $T=RS$, if the scaling is performed first, followed by the rotation. The complete transformation of a point $p$ to its image $p^\prime$ is then $p^\prime=Tp$.

Edit: In response to comments below, the point about which the transformation is performed can give different resulting outcomes. Compare scaling the rectangle with bounding box $(2,2)$, $(4,6)$ by a factor of $2$ about the points $(4,6)$ and $(3,5)$. The distances from the scaled point are doubled, which produces the same size rectangle, but it is positioned differently as the centre of the transformation was different.

Result from scaling the rectangle about the point $(4,6)$

[image: Scale rectangle about (4,6)]

Result from scaling the rectangle about the point $(3,5)$

[image: Scale rectangle about (3,5)]

Comment: Hi, just a question, if you have a rectangle, and you scale it  by 2 in the top right edge point, translating it to the origin will make  the  scale matrix multiplication of that point to (0,0) , and translating it back will leave it in the same place which won't reflect the desired 2x scaling. I think I'm missing something but I don't know what.

Comment: @etragu Yes, but you are scaling with that point as the centre, so it should be unmoved during the transformation. The bottom left corner will also be twice as far away now, which is what you would expect with scaling by two.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, I was doing it wrong, didn't realize that whilst resizing from a point the rectangle, the pivot should have been the opposite of the dragging point. Everything is working fine now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Given $(x,y)$

Proceeding in the order you mention plug each relation into the next tagged equation if so required in an algorithm.

Rotate by angle $t$ counter clockwise i.e., multiply by rotation matrix $A$

$$ A=[ (\cos(t), - \sin (t)) ,\, (\sin(t),  \cos (t)) ]$$

$$ c=x \cos(t)-y \sin (t); \quad d=x \sin(t)+ y \cos (t); \tag2$$

Scale factor $m$

$$ x3 =m. c;\,y3= m.d; \tag3 $$

Shift  back to starting origin

$$ x_{new}= x3-h;\,y_{new}= y3-k. \tag4 $$

EDIT1  (after OP's edit)

Given $(x,y)$

Rotate by angle $t$ counter clockwise i.e., multiply by rotation matrix $A$

$$ A=[ (\cos(t), - \sin (t)) ,\, (\sin(t),  \cos (t)) ]$$

$$ p=x \cos(t)-y \sin (t); \quad q=x \sin(t)+ y \cos (t); \tag5$$

$$ r= c + (p-c).{Xscale} ; \, s= d + (q-d).{Yscale}\tag6 $$

Comment: This rotates and scales with the same origin. How can I do exactly this but with different origins for rotation and scaling?

Comment: The operations are essentially the same. Please mention which new origin coordinates, what  next rotation operation in what order...

Comment: Ok so since (h,k) is the origin for rotation, then let's say I want to scale around a different point (i,j) after rotating it, how would you do that?

Comment: Write down line by line as indicated

Comment: I edited my question for clarity

Comment: Did I understand properly? Please check